# Receiving asynchronous user and external input using ncurses

Tags: c, input, ncurses

I'm making a 2-player game which is controlled by a player from keyboard and at the same time receives input from a server program using message queues. Initially I tried to implement the player console in the parent process and make a child process to react to messages from the server, but every time I modified the screen with the child process it deleted all the changes I made in the parent process - in other words, the processes had separate screens. It looks like there has to be one process which manages both the keyboard input and the server input, but I have no idea how to do this asynchronously.

Does anyone know how to do it? Alternatively, what other libraries could I use to make a game like that with a GUI?

Comment: why not using threads ? or same global screen structure ? not using a copy of it.There is libraries for message passing for doing asynchronous actions,like dbus,zmq or other fast ipc techniques.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if anyone's interested, I have the solution. I used the STDIN_FILENO stream from unistd.h and the poll function to read data from both the keyboard and the pipe which informs about messages from the server.